# What is the name of the theme of the sample code on the Android Developer site?

Tags: android, android-studio, coding-style, android-theme

Like the code theme on this image below (https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/domain-layer#use-cases-kotlin) :

[The Light Code Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abHsa.png)

[The Dark Code Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KKeS.png)

It looks really nice and I want to use the theme in AndroidStudio.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you manage to find the Dark Code theme same as in android documentation?

Comment: @pasty I haven't found the exact same one, but the Xcode-Dark theme is similar to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the android studio style by
android studio -> file -> setting -> color scheme
and you can choose the Dracula style

and another way to change the android studio style by the plugin
android studio -> file -> setting -> plugins -> tab marketplace
and search "Material Theme UI" for suggestion many theme

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I would like to know what is the name of the theme in the picture above, it doesn't seem to be Dracula Theme or Material Theme UI.

Comment: you can find this theme in Material Theme UI plugins.
there is too many themes you can find. sulv